# SQL phpmyadmin Create a table to store grades of a student in a specific subject

Tags: sql, database

How I can create a table and link it that take from student table his id And from subject table its id
And store grades on Grade table ?

Student (student_id, name , mail)
Subject (id, name)
Grade table is what I need to create and store for each student a grade of a specific subject

Sorry for this mess.

Comment: So... You need a table with `student_id`, `subject_id`, and `grade`?

Comment: Yes , and if I want a query to update the data from the grade table, what should I do ?

Comment: It sounds like the terms you're looking for are the SQL `JOIN` keyword and the concept of table normalization.  The table you're describing essentially holds a many-to-many relationship between the two tables you already have, adding a few data elements of its own specific to that relationship.